# If WooCommerce Stock Updates, Also Update Specified Field Values

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to have a function that should update the Est. Dispatch Date Field ) in whenever WooCommerce Stock Value / Stock Amount changes even when order is placed and stock amount is reduced by woocommerce.

I am unable to achieve this since I am unable to get variations ids and there stock amounts, based on which it should also update that variation's est. dispatch date field as below:

SCENARIO 1: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkCeO.png

SCENARIO 2: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/swBDV.png

The Est. Dispatch date field is different for each variation ID. Likewise for the 1st variation, its name is cuzd-prod-general-v1, for the 2nd its cuzd-prod-general-v2 and so on for every product's variation.

I would like to place this code into my functions.php file to work. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using below code. Maybe it will help someone.

```
// Values to be updated
    $in_stock   = '1,5';
    $out_of_stock   = '20,30';
    $in_stock_s     = '5';
    $out_of_stock_s = '30';

//FOR VARIATIONS

// Get variations        
    $args = array(
                 'post_type'     => 'product_variation',
                 'post_status'   => array( 'private', 'publish' ),
                 'numberposts'   => -1,
                 'orderby'       => 'menu_order',
                 'order'         => 'asc',
                 'post_parent'   => $post->ID
             );
             $variations = get_posts( $args ); 

    foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {

                 $variation_id           = absint( $variation->ID );$variable_id = $this['variation_id'];
                 $variation_post_status  = esc_attr( $variation->post_status );
                 $variation_data         = get_post_meta( $variation_id );
                 $variation_data['variation_post_id'] = $variation_id;


    // Get specific data from the certain custom fields using get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $single );
    $stock = get_post_meta( $variation_data['variation_post_id'], '_stock', true ); 


    if ($stock < 1) {
        update_post_meta( $variation_data['variation_post_id'], 'cuzd-prod-general-v', $out_of_stock ); 
        } else {
            update_post_meta( $variation_data['variation_post_id'], 'cuzd-prod-general-v', $in_stock );
            }
    }

// FOR GENERAL PRODUCT META

$product_id = $_GET['post'];

    // Get specific data from the certain custom fields using get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $single );
    $stock = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_stock', true ); 


    if ($stock < 1) {
        update_post_meta( $product_id, 'cuzd-prod-general-s', $out_of_stock );
        update_post_meta( $product_id, 'cuzd-prod-date-s', $out_of_stock_s );   
        } else {
            update_post_meta( $product_id, 'cuzd-prod-general-s', $in_stock );
            update_post_meta( $product_id, 'cuzd-prod-date-s', $in_stock_s );
            }
```